# Visual Studio Load Test Parse Dependent Requests Option

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing, performance-testing

We noticed a significant time spent on loading css and js even after bundling them in asp.net MVC application (with load of 500 concurrent users with think time 5second). Looking at traces most of time has been spent on CSS and JS loads.

We have turned "Parse Dependent Requests" option to true.

Could someone please confirm whether the Visual Studio Load Test respects the `Cache-Control :Public`? In other worlds, does it cache the HTML page just like browsers do?

Thank you.

Comment: Has your question been answered? If not then what else is wanted?

Answer (score 1):

This precious [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/billbar/archive/2007/01/22/simulation-of-browser-caching-in-vsts-load-tests-and-web-tests.aspx) explains how Cache-Control works in Visual Studio load test.

Cache-control does not cache directly request, but emulates HTTP cache headers on the virtual user. This setting is true for all dependent requests.

Number of cached requests is affected by the number of virtual users and the property "Percentage of New Users". It's important to undestand that every new virtual user have an empty cache. So it will always download everything.

I have the same problems in the past but because load testing is often focused on page & ajax calls (and not on ressources : images, css, js, ...), I have created a very simple web test plugin to filter invalid requests.

One example is available [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edglas/archive/2008/07/17/dependent-request-filter.aspx).

Comment: The Web Testing Quick reference Guide on Codeplex has several discussions of how caching works and can be controlled. For example, page 186 shows how to completely disable caching of all dependent requests. See http://vsptqrg.codeplex.com